# Loading social graph in Spring/Hibernate - Hibernate session duration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My app uses a social graph. Each person object has a many-to-many List of other people that person is connected to. My belief is that by using @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY), my List doesn't get looked up until/unless I perform an operation on the collection.

My main question is this : If I look up a person this way, and then associate that person object with a long-lived HTTP session (e.g. session.setAttribute("user", person)), what exactly gets stored? If I try to access a person in the user's graph through the session-associated object, will Hibernate barf because the Hibernate session has expired?

Probably the root of this is that I really don't understand when a Hibernate session begins and ends in Spring MVC, so if someone wants to help explain that, that would be really terrific (using @Transactional at service level and getHibernateTemplate at DAO level)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a Hibernate session begins and ends within a request.

If you are storing the `Person` object in the session, only the object will be stored, the Hibernate session would end.

Even if it would, the idea of tieing a Hibernate session to a session would be a very bad idea, because:

- Underneath a session is a JDBC connection, so you would need to keep a separate JDBC connection open for each HTTP session (each user), which would very quickly hit resource limitations.

I think you'd be better off with a the [Open Session in View](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) pattern and the [OpenSessionInViewInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html).  That way your associations will be lazy loaded as you need them, but you won't keep lots of connections open.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the OpenSessionInViewInterceptor and it's working fine. I'm just trying to figure out the best way to associate user information with long-lived http sessions in a way that plays nice with Spring and Hibernate.